# Android SSL socket Certificate Revocation Checking

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl-certificate

This is a Android project.i wrote a ssl socket use SSLcontext.but,i meet a problem .i don't know how to check Certificate Revocation list.i want to know how to check it. i have a crl file,how to configure it? who can help me

Comment: Take a look at this link [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also it would be better if you could share your code or what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line can help you, it's not recommended, but short way.

```
asyncHttpClient.setSSLSocketFactory(MySSLSocketFactory.getFixedSocketFactory());
```